# Extension of a zero functional from $H_0^1(\Omega)$ to $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I would like to ask for a second (or third) opinion on an argument I used. I think it is fine, but I would like only to check whether I am letting some detail pass.

The situation is the following. Suppose I have a linear functional $T = A + B$ that maps the space $X = [H_0^1(\Omega)]^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (here $\Omega$ is a bounded interval of the real line). Moreover, for each $U \in X$, $T(U) = 0$, therefore $T=0$ in $X'$ (the dual of $X$). Here I say $T$ belongs to the dual because it is the zero functional, which is trivially linear and continuous.

Okay, now: for each part of the functional ($A$ and $B$) separately, I have continuity in $Y = [L^2(\Omega)]^n$, that is, there exists $C>0$ such that $$|A(U)|,|B(U)| \leqslant C\|U\|_Y.$$

Now here is the argument I want to use: since $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $H^1(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega)$, I can always approximate $H^1$-functions by $H_0^1$-functions in the $L^2$-topology. Therefore, since $T(U) = 0$ for all $U \in X$, then $T(U)=0$ for all $U \in Z := [H^1(\Omega)]^n$. The proof would be something like: let $U \in Z$ and $(U_n)$ a sequence in $X$ such that $U_n \to U$ in $Y.$ Moreover, it is true that $T(U_n) \to T(U)$ (due to the way $A$ and $B$ are defined). So $0 = T(U_n) \to T(U)$ and therefore $T(U) = 0$ for all $U \in Z.$

Is there any holes in this argument?

I appreciate, in advance, any comment.

Comment: If you are unsure, sometimes it helps to be more rigorous.
If you want to be more rigorous, you can use different variable names for the operators which operate on different spaces. For example, use $\hat T:Z\to \Bbb R$ and $T:X\to \Bbb R$, instead of calling both $T$. Similarly with $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Agreed. Also, your argument can be written more generally (and by omission of details more cleanly) as: assume $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous function (not necessarily linear and not necessarily between vector spaces) such that $f(z)=y_0$ for all $z$ in a dense subspace of $X$. Then $f\equiv y_0$

Comment: @supinf thank you very much for your answer. Does it mean that my argument is - modulus some writing issues - correct?

Comment: @Bananach thank you very much for your answer. Does it mean that my argument is - modulus some writing issues - correct?

Comment: Depends. What is your continuous function, what is it defined on, on which space does the additivity equation hold,...?

Comment: E.g. if your T is defined on all of $L^2$ but it's only equal to the sum of the two continuos functionals on a subspace, you get a problem

Comment: It seems that you successfully extended the zero function on $H^1_0$ to $H^1$.

Comment: @Bananach The functional $T$ is defined for functions in $Z$ and is continuous w.r.t the $Y$-topology.

Comment: @daw, thank you very much.